# How does a ClickListener know which data to return?

Tags: android

I have the following ClickListener:

```
        itemList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        itemList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("TEXT", ((TextView) v).getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

It worked fine when I used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 for the item layout. But when I made a custom layout consisting of the following, it stopped working.

```
<RelativeLayout>
TextView TextView(this is what I want) TextView
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: It might have something to do with one of the TextViews being clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view returned in OnItemClickListener is the root View of the clicked item. In your custom layout for listview, it would return the root view of the row ,that is the RelativeLayout. Once you get a hold of the RelativeLayout you can get your desired textview (getChildAt('what ever you want') or query by name or query by id)and get the values.

Comment: So v is my RelativeLayout? I want to do something like b.putString("TEXT", ((RelativeLayout) v).getChildAt(position).toString());?   I'm trying that but it returns "android.widget.TextView@44ed...."

Comment: `getChildAt(position)` is not what you want to do. You want the second child, but `position` is the position in the ListView in which the clicked item is located. In all but three cases, you're going to get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You should do `getChildAt(2)` to return your View, cast it to a TextView, then call `getText()` on that View. Alternately, just call `((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview2)).getText()` where textview2 is the id you've given to the second TextView in your XML.