# ClickListener and ListView Item Layout

Tags: java, android

I have the following ClickListener on my ListView. My item layout is a RelativeLayout with 3 TextViews. I'm trying to return the value of the list item but I'm getting "android.widget.TextView@44ed....". What am I doing wrong?

```
        itemList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        itemList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("TEXT", ((RelativeLayout) v).getChildAt(position).toString());
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a ClickListener know which data to return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147239/how-does-a-clicklistener-know-which-data-to-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [TextView.getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v;
TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(position);
b.putString("TEXT", textView.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

b.putString("TEXT", ((RelativeLayout) v).getChildAt(position).toString();  instead try doing this

b.putString("TEXT", (a.getItemAtposition(position).toString);

if this doesn't work please provide more info about the error..Hope this helps